# iPhone google maps v3 pans after pinch zoom

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, pinch, pan

I have a problem developing a web application for iPhone. When I visit a simple example like http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html in an iPhone and do pinch zoom the map pans when I release the fingers from the screen. This makes the map end up somewhere else than the place I zoomed to.

Is there some way to prevent the map from panning after pinch zoom release?

Comment: This question has also been asked on the google maps v3 google group (no solution yet at time of writing) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/P-Zya3J8qrE

Comment: Seen the same issue. For me it pans only when i remove both fingers at the same time, if I lift one finger at a time, it doesn't pan.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the iPhone's use of touch screen technology - especially Cocoa - can have some odd effects when it comes to viewing a web app on a mobile device.

I cannot fathom why, but it seems like such multi-touch gestures, such as pinching, have a relatively odd effect on non-native applications.

The only thing I can suggest is using Objective-C and getting to work on porting your application to run as an app on the iDevice. This will remove the problems you are having, but it will not rid you of the issue that you are trying to develop a web app.